# Install terminal application after installing minimal desktop Unity on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I installed Ubuntu server 14.04.. and to get a minimal desktop, I installed Unity desktop with the no-install-recommends option. The desktop was installed minimally but so is the terminal application missing.

How do I get this one application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, this will bring you to a terminal screen. From there you can `apt-get` your preferred terminal. I recommend terminator.

To leave press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks. What is the default terminal in Unity?

Comment: to my knowledge it is still gnome-terminal
    sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal

Comment: How do I get it shown in the launcher? When I had installed the full Unity desktop, I used to see the Terminal application in the dash and could just drag it to the launcher.

Answer (score -3):

1. search Application manager in menu
2. search "Terminal" and install it
3. in menu is terminal